# pentaho kettle : get row count from stream

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

I would like to get the total record count from the get rows from result output and then pass  it to parent job.

Any suggestions ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try using "Group BY" or "Memory Group By" step to get the total count of the rows. select the type as : Number of rows in the step and it will return you the total count.

You can read the wiki also : http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Group+By

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for reply Rishu. Issue is , Column names are dynamic in input stream and we need to get count always. :-( thus not sure what to define in field "Subject". ( Currently i set Name as "cnt" , type as number of values (N) with always retrun row to true ) . Any idea how it will work for all set of resultset ?

Comment: Just use "Number of rows(Without field argument)"

Comment: I do not see above option Number of rows(Without field argument) and if i use directly without subject and type set to "Number of Values(N)", it gives error at runeitme saying subject is null . I am using 4.3 version. Can you share screen shot of sample and how group by is configured ?

Answer (score 1):

this will be easily achieved adding a **Get Value From Sequence** step

if you name, for instance, a new var (see name of value on screenshot) called "counter" now you will have a row counter on this var[image: see this screenshot]

at the last row you get this counter value and you get all the rows processed in the trans.

Comment: there is limit to solution. max value can be anything